# Máscara de dados

Tags: java, mysql

Estou utilizando uma JFormattedTextField com a máscara (##:##) para que o usuário insira uma hora e meu programa faça a busca no banco retornando os valores correspondetes a essa hora.

Meu problema é que no banco as informações estão sem o ":", ou seja, se o usuário inserir "15:00" não irá retornar nada, pois está cadastrado como 1500. O formato dos dados de hora no banco são INT.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como posso solucionar isto?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `replace()`.

Exemplo:

```
String hora = "15:00";
String novaHora = hora.replace(":", "");
```